# best way to import data from a php into tableview

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am writing my first iOS iPhone app for local Paragliding/hang gliding club.  We have some wind talkers on the hill that are hooked into a server. I want to display the data as both a table, and also graph the information in the iPhone app on seperate pages.  Server owner said he can re-write a PHP that can push CSV or XML to a URL with info from hill which has "timestamp, wind direction, gust speed, lull, average etc"

What is the easiest format and way to get the data into a `UITableView`?

Comment: @veggyaurus, use web-services to get data from server. There are built-in and third party libraries for xml parsing & json parsing....ask server owner to provide web-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XML Parser or JSON Parser to fetch webservice data. There is a nice tutorial here for JSON Parsing

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

For XML Parsing you can take a look on this

http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/08/parsing-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html

I think JSON will be the easiest way